# Bind the right Alt key + key to another key on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a key remapper called "keyremaplinux" (source: https://github.com/kozikow/keyremaplinux). It works well but it's not very portable and requires a big configuration. I'd like something that I can ideally take to work and onto other Linux (CentOS primarily) machines with little effort. The solution should work with everything and not be program-specific.

### What I want

Pressing the right-alt key + another key will input a different key. For example, my entire number-line is mapped to the qwerty row, like this:

```
right-alt + q = 1
right-alt + w = 2
right-alt + e = 3
right-alt + r = 4
right-alt + t = 5
right-alt + y = 6
right-alt + u = 7
```

and

```
right-alt + shift + q = !
right-alt + shift + w = @
right-alt + shift + e = #
right-alt + shift + r = $
right-alt + shift + t = %
right-alt + shift + y = ^
right-alt + shift + u = &
```

and misc bindings like

```
right-alt + a = (
right-alt + s = )
right-alt + d = {
right-alt + f = }
```

### What I tried

`xbindkeys` - This tool looks like it can't differentiate between the left-alt key and the right-alt key. When I use xbindkeys -k and press right-alt key + 1, it returns "m:0x18 + c:10 | Alt+Mod2 + 1" which is the same as if I press left-alt key + 1

`sxhkd` - According to this GitHub post, you can't trigger left/right alt keys separately. https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd/issues/89. Though according to this other forum, you can map to left/right alt (just not from) https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155613&p=3. Just re-iterating - I don't use Arch. I use CentOS. The forum just happens to be from Arch.